# Why does Python use the None type hint instead of NoneType?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

For Python's `None` object, the type hint `None` is used instead of its actual type, `NoneType`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

> Note that None as a type hint is a special case and is replaced by type(None).

I find this confusing and no further explanation is given.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a design choice. There's no particular reason behind it.

Writing `def fn(x: None) -> None` is more concise than `def fn(x: NoneType) -> NoneType` (and IMHO also clearer).

It's also consistent with other type hints: `List`, `Dict`, etc, which are all a single word (the same as the associated built-in function) with an uppercase first letter.

Comment: Accepted your answer but can't agree with your assessment of this design choice. List and Dict are clearly types but None is both a value and a type which is jarring to me. NoneType would be clearer.

Comment: @BeauBarker I think they most probably wanted consistency with other type hints. `None` is the only object where this happens since it already has an uppercase letter.

Comment: @BeauBarker -- if it helps, PEP 484 does let you use values inside types to a limited extent. For example, `Union[Literal["r"], Literal["w"]]` is a type meaning the corresponding value can only ever be the strs "r" or "w" -- and the only reason this isn't spelled `Union["r", "w"]` is because this would be too ambiguous so long as forward references exist. But this ambiguity doesn't exist for None, so it's fine to refer to the value directly. And since there's only one value of type `type(None)` (e.g. it's a "singleton" type), it's also fine to treat `type(None)` and `None` as interchangeable.

Comment: Granted, this justification is a bit post ex facto: Literal types/basic dependent types were added only about a year ago and postdates the original PEP 484 spec by quite a bit. But it help make it possible to think about `None` as slightly less of a special case: e.g. instead of viewing it as both a value and a type, you can view it as just a value -- and mixing values and types is ok in a few constrained cases.

Comment: But you cannot write  -> type(None),  that is werid and not consistant